# Update composer not working

Tags: git, yii2, composer-php

I am trying to install new extension in my yii2 project

```
"miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "*"
```

and added above line in composer.json file under "require-dev" section 
but when I try to update composer using

```
composer update
```

command it will show me

> [RuntimeException]  Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d  'git'
>   is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable
>   program or batch file.

error message .
how do i solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have git installed?

Comment: yes i have install git

Comment: Try running this command in your CMD.

composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:dev-master"

Then run composer update again.

Comment: now it showing "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Composer\Package\RootPackage::getConfig()
in C:\Users\Machine-06\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin
\Config\ConfigBuilder.php on line 111" error message

Comment: Try running composer self-update on your CMD.